# JQuery not appending html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, again, I'm new to JQuery but for whatever reason JQuery isn't appending the form when I click the "Add Scenario" button. It's not even getting to the function involving #add. I have a breakpoint set on the .on() line and it doesn't seem to recognize it when I click.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#add').on('submit',function(e)
    {
        var form = "<div class='form'>\
        <h3> Scenario </h3>\
        <form id='scenario'>\
            <div>Name: <input type='text' name='ScenarioName'> </div>\
            <div>Rate of Investment Return (While Working): <input type='number' name='Working'></div>\
            <div>Rate of Investment Return (Retired): <input type='number' name='Retired'></div>\
            <div>Desired Retirement Yearly Income: <input type='number' name='desiredInc'></div>\
            <div><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div>\
        </form>\
        <div><button id='add' type='submit'>Add Scenario </button></div>\
    </div>"
        $('body').append($(form));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```
<body>
    <div class='form'>
        <h3> Basic Information </h3>
        <form id='basic'>
            <div>Year of Birth: <input type='number' name='YOB'> </div> 
            <div>Current Savings: <input type='number' name='CurrSav'> 
            </div>  
            <div>Expected Retirement Age: <input type='number' name='RetAge'></div>     
            <div>Life expectancy: <input type='number' name='LifeExp'>
            </div>  
            <div><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div> 
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class='form'>
        <h3> Scenario </h3>
        <form id='scenario'>
            <div>Name: <input type='text' name='ScenarioName'> </div>
            <div>Rate of Investment Return (While Working): <input type='number' name='Working'></div>
            <div>Rate of Investment Return (Retired): <input type='number' name='Retired'></div>
            <div>Desired Retirement Yearly Income: <input type='number' name='desiredInc'></div>
            <div><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div>
        </form>
        <div><button id='add' type='submit'>Add Scenario </button></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're listening for the submit event of a form, and the button is not inside that form, so how is that supposed to work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/submit) handler you need to use the [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/click) handler - submit event is for the form element, you are registering the handler for the button element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add').on('click', function (e) {
        var form = "<div class='form'>\
        <h3> Scenario </h3>\
        <form id='scenario'>\
            <div>Name: <input type='text' name='ScenarioName'> </div>\
            <div>Rate of Investment Return (While Working): <input type='number' name='Working'></div>\
            <div>Rate of Investment Return (Retired): <input type='number' name='Retired'></div>\
            <div>Desired Retirement Yearly Income: <input type='number' name='desiredInc'></div>\
            <div><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div>\
        </form>\
    </div>";
        $(this).parent().before(form)
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add').on('click', function(e) {
    var form = "<div class='form'>\
        <h3> Scenario </h3>\
        <form id='scenario'>\
            <div>Name: <input type='text' name='ScenarioName'> </div>\
            <div>Rate of Investment Return (While Working): <input type='number' name='Working'></div>\
            <div>Rate of Investment Return (Retired): <input type='number' name='Retired'></div>\
            <div>Desired Retirement Yearly Income: <input type='number' name='desiredInc'></div>\
            <div><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div>\
        </form>\
    </div>";
    $(this).parent().before(form)
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form'>
  <h3> Basic Information </h3>

  <form id='basic'>
    <div>Year of Birth:
      <input type='number' name='YOB' />
    </div>
    <div>Current Savings:
      <input type='number' name='CurrSav' />
    </div>
    <div>Expected Retirement Age:
      <input type='number' name='RetAge' />
    </div>
    <div>Life expectancy:
      <input type='number' name='LifeExp' />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class='form'>
  <h3> Scenario </h3>

  <form id='scenario'>
    <div>Name:
      <input type='text' name='ScenarioName' />
    </div>
    <div>Rate of Investment Return (While Working):
      <input type='number' name='Working' />
    </div>
    <div>Rate of Investment Return (Retired):
      <input type='number' name='Retired' />
    </div>
    <div>Desired Retirement Yearly Income:
      <input type='number' name='desiredInc' />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </div>
  </form>
  <div>
    <button id='add' type='submit'>Add Scenario</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind, very briefly, explaining the difference between the two. Or point me to something that would help. I guess 'click' is pretty self explanatory but what makes 'submit' different

Comment: @sreya `submit` event only can be used for **HTMLFormElement** not for a `button`

Comment: The submit event is not triggered by the input element, it is by the form element when it is submitted... when you click on a submit button it internally triggers a form submission which will cause the submit event to trigger

Comment: @sreya in your case since the event is registered to the button itself you need to use the click event

Comment: Okay cool, thanks! Another thing I noticed is that when I duplicated my form that when I clicked the "Add scenario" button on the duplicates no action occurs. Is there any was to change that?

Comment: @sreya I don't think the button needs to be duplicated... anyway it is a very common issue how to deal with dynamic element events... you need to use event delegation to do it... one more thing to keep in mind is ID of an element must be unique always.... so if you are adding a new add scenario button it should have a different ID

Comment: @sreya see the update... you should have only one `add scenario` button... check the attached fiddle to see it in action

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#add').on('click', function(e) // <-- click instead of submit
    {
        var form = "<div class='form'>\
        <h3> Scenario </h3>\
        <form id='scenario'>\
            <div>Name: <input type='text' name='ScenarioName'> </div>\
            <div>Rate of Investment Return (While Working): <input type='number' name='Working'></div>\
            <div>Rate of Investment Return (Retired): <input type='number' name='Retired'></div>\
            <div>Desired Retirement Yearly Income: <input type='number' name='desiredInc'></div>\
            <div><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div>\
        </form>\
        <div><button id='add' type='submit'>Add Scenario </button></div>\
    </div>";
        $('body').append(form); // no need to wrapping with jQuery
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click event handler is wrong.

The `submit` event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form. It can only be attached to `form` elements.

Change this

```
 $('#add').on('submit',function(e)
```

to:

```
$('#add').on('click',function(e)
```

Comment: bah, idk who answered first